# Bad request on ProcessUserAuthorization (DotNetOpenAuth 4.2.2.13055)

Tags: dotnetopenauth

I'm trying to upgrade the `DotNetOpenAuth` verson to `4.2.2.13055`, in the Google dotnet client library.
So I downloaded the latest dlls - DotNetOpenAuth.Core, DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2, etc. (we still don't work with NuGet).

I made a small change (changed the way I construct NativeApplcationClient with client_id and client_secret) to support the new version.
Then, I tried to run a sample we have in our samples repository (e.g. https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Tasks.SimpleOAuth2/Program.cs?repo=samples), and I got a bad request error, as following:

```
 DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException: Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response. --->
 System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.StandardWebRequestHandler.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request, DirectWebRequestOptions opt
ions)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.StandardWebRequestHandler.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request, DirectWebRequestOptions opt
ions)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.StandardWebRequestHandler.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.GetDirectResponse(HttpWebRequest webRequest)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.RequestCore(IDirectedProtocolMessage request)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.Request(IDirectedProtocolMessage requestMessage)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.ClientBase.UpdateAuthorizationWithResponse(IAuthorizationState authorizationState, EndUserAu
thorizationSuccessAuthCodeResponse authorizationSuccess)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.UserAgentClient.ProcessUserAuthorization(IAuthorizationState authorizationState, IDirectedPr
otocolMessage response)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.UserAgentClient.ProcessUserAuthorization(Uri actualRedirectUrl, IAuthorizationState authoriz
ationState)
   at Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth.NativeApplicationClient.ProcessUserAuthorization(String authCode,
 IAuthorizationState authorizationState) in c:\code.google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default_oauth2\Src\GoogleApis.Au
thentication.OAuth2\DotNetOpenAuth\NativeApplicationClient.cs:line 102
   at Google.Apis.Samples.TasksOAuth2.Program.GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient arg) in c:\code.google.com\google
-api-dotnet-client\samples_oauth2\Tasks.SimpleOAuth2\Program.cs:line 73
   at Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.OAuth2Authenticator`1.LoadAccessToken() in c:\code.google.com\google-api-dotnet-
client\default_oauth2\Src\GoogleApis.Authentication.OAuth2\OAuth2Authenticator.cs:line 124
```

I noticed also that there is a different in the second request (in exchanging the code with a token): Authorization header was added to the request, and the body was missing my client_id and client_secret.

Similar code worked on old version - 4.0.0.11165,
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if the problem is that the newer DNOA version supports putting client credentials in the HTTP header *by default*. If you create your Client class, passing in a different client credential provider into the constructor, it may work for you.

To change the behavior from using the HTTP Authorization header back to passing client credentials in the POST entity, instantiate your ClientBase-derived class passing in this as a parameter to the constructor:

```
ClientCredentialApplicator.PostParameter(clientSecret)
```

Comment: But as I mentioned in the new version client_id and client_secret are missing in the token exchange request (grant_type=authorization_code).
BEFORE the change the body contained code, 
redirect_uri, grant_type=authorization_code, client_id and client_secret.

IN THE NEW REQUEST client_id and client_secret are missing and Authorization header was added to the request

Comment: Then you just confirmed my answer.

Comment: I needed to do this for box.com api also.